# SQL Script in DAX ( Many different Joins )

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I have a problem in Power BI with DAX, i want to do SQL joins in Dax , i made my data modelling with my tree tables
Table 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WClwI.png)

table 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKLav.png)

table 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhzaa.png)

I want to do with DAX this table joining in this SQL query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYljC.png)

I want to create a table with the joining bloc

Can you help me ?

Kind Regards ;

I try to do it on power query but i have some speed issue

Answer (score 1):

In power bi, you would address this by creating relationships in the model:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships

Please note that all joins are equivalent to outer joins in SQL.  Some of what is in your ssample query is not valid SQL syntax - you can't have duplicate table names, "join" is repeated.  However, if you wish to filter a table like `T3.U2 = 'NW'`, you can simply add that as a WHERE clause in the query to import the data into the model or filter out the rows you want with PowerQuery (using the edit queries dialogue in power bi).